# Laravel get last inserted data

Tags: php, laravel

Please find the code below, Here I am trying to create master record and based on the id I am adding related data.

```
    $country = new Country;

    $country->name = $request->post('country-name');
    $country->xyz  = $request->post('xyz');

    if($country->save()) {
        $n = count($request->post('bname'));

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $dimention = new BoxDimentions;

            $dimention->name = $request->post('bname')[$i];
            $dimention->xyz  = $request->post('xyz')[$i];
            $dimention->cid  = $country->id;

            $dimention->save();
        }
    }
```

Is there any inbuilt laravel function I can use to get all the information about country & BoxDimentions(including id, date time stamp etc) after the operation?

I have created a relation in the Country Model class "boxes" which will return all the box information. I know I can fetch the data using another query with the last created country id. I dont want to go for another query because I believe we have all the data is in our hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well unfortunately `save()` returns bool.

Your way around this would be using `create()` static wrapper that way you can get the recently created model instance.

You proppably want to refactor that code, so in your `Country` model you would prolly create a function like this (assuming u have defined relationships Country and BoxDimensions):

Your Country Model:

```
public function addBoxDimensions(array $data){

    return $this->boxes()->create($data);
}
```

Then your controller would look something like this:

```
$country = new Country;

$country->name = $request->post('country-name');

$country->xyz  = $request->post('xyz');

if($country->save()) {

    $n = count($request->post('bname'));

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

            // Here I will use relationships to create box dimensions for given country that's why I do not need to initialize BoxDimentions
           // $dimention = new BoxDimentions;

           $dimention = $country->addBoxDimensions([
             'name' = $request->post('bname')[$i],
             'xyz'  = $request->post('xyz')[$i],
             'cid'  = $country->id 
            ]);
       }
        //here you can return the country with all the box dimentions
        // also used eager loading to load boxdimensions so we can aviod N+1

       return $dimention->load('boxes');  



        }
```

Comment: you have the model when you call `save` on it (it is the thing you are calling `save` on)... `create` is just calling `save` on a new instance

Comment: yes true, however I am returning the country boxes on chain ! So create calls save but then method returns $this->boxes() ;)

Comment: I agree with @lagbox. Also, you're trying to load boxes relationship on box instance. And even if you'll fix it, with this approach an additional query will be executed. And the last problem is that you'll load all boxes that belong to country, not boxes you've just created.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I am not sure if you read my answer right I added the method on Country model from there I load boxes. Yes this will perform an aditional query BUT he will not endup calling a query each time for loop performs right !

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi i thnk he is referring to `$dimention->load('boxes')` .. just a mistake  `$country->load()`

Comment: Yes, but you're returning `BoxDimentions` object from it. And I didn't say that the additional query will be executed in the loop. It will be executed once. But still it's one additional query.

Comment: @lagbox $dimention that is still property of stdObject from Country :) then load() lazy loads boxes from Country! This works propperly had this exact issue earlier today! Or I would say slightly more complex using vue!

Comment: no its a Box .. you are not returning `$this` from that method, you are returning the new Box you created.

Comment: its triggering "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\MassAssignmentException"

Comment: add name , xyz and cid as protected fillable on their models, that should fix the mass asignment exceptionm

Comment: you are still trying to load `boxes` on a `Box` not a `Country` ... calling `create` on a relationship returns the new model you just created ... you are creating a `Box` in your method, so you are returning a `Box` ... now you just have the potentially of an undefined variable if that `for` loop doesn't run

Answer (score 2):

After executing `save()` you'll get model with it's ID. You can access it with `$model->id`. So, you can do something like this:

```
$country = new Country;

$country->name = $request->post('country-name');
$country->xyz  = $request->post('xyz');

$dimentionIds = [];

if ($country->save()) {
    $n = count($request->post('bname'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $dimention = new BoxDimentions;

        $dimention->name = $request->post('bname')[$i];
        $dimention->xyz  = $request->post('xyz')[$i];
        $dimention->cid  = $country->id;

        $dimention->save();

        $dimentionIds[] = $dimention->id;
    }
}

dd($dimentionIds, $country->id);
```

If you need all the data, just save whole object:

```
 $dimentions[] = $dimention;
```

Comment: I think he wants to get all the data, all rows

Comment: @CavidKərimov I thought OP wants just IDs. Thanks for the correction. I've updated my answer.

Comment: am i guessing correct that when you want all the information you mean there might be some columns that get some default values that the database sets, therefor your new instance doesn't have them?

Answer (score 1):

Im still not entirely sure about what you are asking. If it is okay to make new queries something like this:

```
$country->refresh();
```

Would reload the current model from the database and any already loaded relationships fresh from the database.

```
$country->id;
$country->created_at;
$firstBox = $country->boxes->first();
$firstBox->id;
$firstBox->created_at;
```

It seems you would prefer to not have any more queries happen, that is okay as well. As long as there are no default values that your database would set that you need you can actually add these records to the relationship instead of reloading the relationship.

Say you have your country and you loaded that relationship:

```
 $country->load('boxes');
 // or maybe because of eager loading
 $country = Country::where(...)->with('boxes')->first();

 ...
 foreach ( something ) {
     $dimention = new BoxDimentions;
     ...
     $dimention->save();
     $country->boxes->add($dimention);
 }

 return $country;
```

`$country->boxes` would have all the items you had loaded before and all the new records.

If you only want the new ones, you can just set the relationship as the collection of the new ones.

```
$country->setRelation('boxes', $country->newCollection());

foreach ( something ) {
    ...
    $country->boxes->add($dimention);
}
```

Now `$country->boxes` is just those new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already setup the relationship, won't the following do the job for you?, sure this might be another query but it will return the data as a collection and saves you handling this yourself.

```
dd($country->boxes);
```